# How do I pass billing address details to authorize.net Advanced Merchant Integration (AIM) - I am using ruby authorize.net gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorize.net

Is there any way we can pass address details like first_name, last_name and billing address details to authorize.net AIM using ruby authorize.net gem
I didn't get any help from https://github.com/joevandyk/authorize-net to pass address details.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using ActiveMerchant which you can configure to use Authorize.net as the Gateway

see

- http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=23

  - episodes 144 and 145
- http://activemerchant.org/
- https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant
- http://rdoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/master/frames

from rails casts #145

```
response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)
# where credit_card is a hash of all card info
#  - type, number, cvv, first and last name, etc
# and purchase_options is also a hash and contains additional info like billing address
```

Comment: @NaveenKumar If this answer solved your problem, please give it the checkmark.  That will help others who find your question though a search.